# Return Observable from Function that contains subscription and another observable

Tags: angularjs, firebase, rxjs, observable, observers

I am trying to get status of printer connected to my app. Here is the function, I have in one of the page:

```
checkPrinterStatus() { //I want to this this function into an observable
    this.afdb.object('food/settings/printer').snapshotChanges().subscribe((res: any) => {
      const printerSettings = res.payload.val();
      if(printerSettings.isConnected) {
        timer(5000, 3000).pipe(
          switchMap(_ => this.getConnPrinterStatus()),
          distinctUntilChanged()
        ).subscribe(async res => {
          let printerStatus = res;
          return printerStatus; // I want this to be an observable
        });  
      }
    });
    
  }
```

So basically, I am subscribing to my firebase database which provided me a value of wheather the printer is connected/set up or not. If it is connect, I am creating a polling where I call my getConnPrinterStatus() which returns me the status every 3 second if it has changed.

Now, currently, I have this function inside one of my page but I want to turn this function into observable so that I can put this in one of the services and then subscribe to printerStatus value in every page. How can I achieve that? Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkPrinterStatus() { //I want to this this function into an observable
  return this.afdb.object('food/settings/printer').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    switchMap(res => iif(() => res.payload.val().isConnected, timer(5000, 3000).pipe(
        switchMap(_ => this.getConnPrinterStatus()),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
    ))
  );
}
```

This function returns an observable

Comment: But how do I add that firebase subscription together with the timer subscription? My timer subscription depends on the value coming from firebase.

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Here is what I am trying to achieve:
1. My function subscribe to firebase database where I have data stored in a variable which says whether my printer is setup or not.
2. If the printer is setup, in my above code ie. printerSettings.isConnected comes to true, that means my printer is setup so then I am running the timer function which call getConnPrinterStatus() function.

So this whole function works as I posted above. But now I want to turn the printerStatus variable where i have commented into an observable.

Comment: Basically, I want to turn the whole function checkPrinterStatus() into an Observable.

Comment: Thanks :) That was what I was looking for. I didn't knew how to pipe the timer observable inside firebase query. Thanks for help me out!

Comment: quick question, how do I import "iff" ? I cannot find it in rxjs/operators path.

Comment: I was able to import. Its "iif" not "iff" but it gives me error "Argument of type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<SnapshotAction<unknown>, any>'."

Answer (score 0):

You can return an observable from the function `checkPrinterStatus` like this -

```
checkPrinterStatus() {
    
    return this.afdb.object('food/settings/printer').snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
               return res.payload.val().isConnected;
            }),
            filter(isConnected => !!isConnected),
            take(1),//use this if you want only 1 value; otherwise remove it
            switchMap(() => {
                return timer(5000, 3000).pipe(
                              switchMap(_ => this.getConnPrinterStatus()),
                              distinctUntilChanged()
                            )
            })
        )
    
  }
```

Since the function returns an observable, the caller can subscribe the observable return by the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats worked perfectly. I was just looking for how to return the timer observable to outside of my function. Thank you!

Comment: Using iff like I have below will complete if the printer is not online, this will have an orphan subscription waiting in limbo forever

Comment: @AdrianBrand - how iif solves the orphan subscription problem? in your solution as well even if printer offline, the timer will run forever until the caller unsubscribe? Am I missing some concept? iif is simply a solution for if/else kind of thing (specially to return an observable); I guess?

Comment: @user2216584 - Is it possible to wrap the entire thing in a setTimout and if I don't receive any response from timer(5000,3000), I would provide my own reponse? The problem I am facing is, this works perfectly when printer is running or when there is an error inside the printer but if I switch off the printer, my getConnPrinterStatus() takes forever to respond.

Comment: @KartikSolanki setTimeout will make your code unpredictable. I will suggest not to do that. If you know that the printer is offline then remove take(1) and filter and code for not connected case.

Comment: @user2216584 here isConnected means the printer configurations are set up. the timer function this.getConnPrinterStatus() is what provides me the current status of the printer connectivity. so we need the filter code there. but my problem is getConnPrinterStatus() take too long to respond when the printer is switched off. so i am looking for a way to put a timeout where i can provide my own default status if the getConnPrinterStatus() doesn’t respond in for example 5 second.

Comment: @KartikSolanki In the solution, I provided remove the `filter` and `take` operators and then in switchMap return desired observable as per `isConnected` = true or false.

Comment: isConnected - printer setup or not setup | i have another variable isActive which i am setting from the observable value of above timer function. so what i mean is my printer is connected initially but when i turn the printer off in active connection, i need the status from that timer observable in order to set isActive to false. so isConnect has nothing to do with current status. isConnected just gives me whether my printer is set up with configurations or not.

Comment: @user2216584 isConnected is just for whether my printer configurations are saved in the database or not. It doesn’t provide me the actual printer connectivity status.